# LinkDialog on dojo editor having rendering issues in IE8

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, editor, dojo

Dojo 1.6.1 is being used. In IE8 the linkdialog in dojo editor sometimes doesnt render fully. The RHS border on Link dialog doesnt show up sometimes on IE.
Any suggestion how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Adding the following line fixed it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```